# Pig latin script treats different columns in csv file as one single column

Tags: apache-pig

I am just pasting a line from the file for example

The following line is from the file '`airlines_new.txt`' which I am loading into a relation

```
2008,1,3,4,617,615,652,650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,NA                                                                                                             ,NA,NA,NA
```

====================================================

I am using the following query :

```
Airlines_data_schema = LOAD '/user/Jig13517/airlines_new.txt' 
USING PigStorage(' ') AS
(Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayofWeek, DepTime_actual:chararray, CRSDeptime:chararray, Arrtime_actual:chararray, CRSArrtime:chararray, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, TailNum_Plane ,ActualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, Airtime, Arrdelay, Depdelay, Origin,Dest, Distance, Taxiin, Taxiout, Cancelled, CancellationCode, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay);
```

==========================================================

```
B = FOREACH Airlines_data_schema generate $0 ;

dump  B ;
```

=========================================================

Result :

> (Year, Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCar                                                                                                                     rier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDela                                                                                                                     y,Origin,Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,Carrie                                                                                                                     rDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay                   )
>   (2008,1,3,4,617,615,652,650,WN,11,N689SW,95,95,70,2,2,IND,MCI,451,6,19,0,,0,NA,N                                                                                                                     A,NA,NA,NA                                                                     )

It is giving the all columns as single column. But intention is to break these into different columns. Ideally according to my script it should only give only the column "Year".

Answer (score 0):

The records are separated by a comma but in the script you are using ' ' as the delimiter.Modify your script to use ',' as the delimiter in PigStorage.

```
Airlines_data_schema = LOAD '/user/Jig13517/airlines_new.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayofWeek,DepTime_actual:chararray,CRSDeptime:chararray,Arrtime_actual:chararray,CRSArrtime:chararray,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum_Plane,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,Airtime,Arrdelay,Depdelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,Taxiin,Taxiout,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate delimiter needs to be used in this scenario to ensure that the fields are separated .

```
Airlines_data_schema = LOAD '/user/Jig13517/airlines_new.txt' 
USING **PigStorage(',')** AS
(Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayofWeek, DepTime_actual:chararray, CRSDeptime:chararray, Arrtime_actual:chararray, CRSArrtime:chararray, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, TailNum_Plane ,ActualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, Airtime, Arrdelay, Depdelay, Origin,Dest, Distance, Taxiin, Taxiout, Cancelled, CancellationCode, Diverted, CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay);.
```

This will ensure you to access each of the fields which are separated in the csv by  ',' .